# ¿Como cambiar el mensaje de un commit en github despues de hacer 'git push'?

Tags: git, github, push, repositorio

Hice un commit con un mensaje incorrecto y de inmediato hice push. Use git commit --amend -m '...' Para modificar el mensaje, pero quiero saber si en mi próximo push esa modificación se verá reflejada en mi repositorio remoto o se quedara así para siempre.
Mi repositorio es GitHub. Hay una forma de cambiarlo allí, si no se realiza el cambio haciendo un próximo push?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma de empujar dicho cambio y reemplazar el otro sería haciendo un `git push -f`:

```
git push -f el-resto-de-cosas-necesarias
```

Según como tengas configurada tu rama local, podría no ser necesario agregar nada sobre el `-f` (por ejemplo, si la rama tiene su `upstream` configurada). Esto **no** es recomendable hacerlo sobre ramas en las que trabajan otras personas porque esa revisión que empujaste previamente ya pudo haber sido halada por otros desarrolladores. Si es una rama de un feature donde solo tu trabajas o es un repositorio propio donde nadie mas trabaja, te puedes sentir libre de hacerlo sin consecuencias.